# Android installation in multiple systems

Tags: android, sdk

I and my team are planning to develop an application. I have already downloaded and installed eclipse juno, sdk and required plugins/updates. It took lot of time for me to do all these (download speed - 45 to 60kbps).

Same operation needs to be performed in others (my team) system too. Can I just copy all the files in C drive (sdk & workspace) and paste it in others C drive to save time? do you think it will work? If your answer is NO Is their any other way to do it?

OS : win7 64 bit and some have 32 bit.

Comment: You need to transfer the installation files that you downloaded, and copy those. Simply transferring the installed files will not work. Among other things, there is the registry to consider.

Comment: If you downloaded ADT bundle, you can reuse it in all systems. If you did using the exe self extractor , you can use the same exe to install everywhere. And download platforms to one system, then distribute it everywhere

Comment: I'm totally new to this field. so still have some doubts. I have a sdk, adt.zip, eclipse and jdk. I copied all these files in my friends system in the same location (i.e sdk in C drive and all other in a folder called Android in D drive). is that enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can use same sdk for any machine and you can also use same eclipse on another machines but you need same machine(if your eclipse is 64 bit it wont work on 32 bit machine). so you need to download 32 bit eclipse for 32 bit os and 64 bit eclipse for 64 bit os.
And if you have downloaded the zip file of android plugins then you can use same plugin for any eclipse.

For any doubt follow [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) link

Comment: I'm totally new to this field. so still have some doubts. I have a sdk, adt.zip, eclipse and jdk. I copied all these files in my friends system in the same location (i.e sdk in C drive and all other in a folder called Android in D drive). is that enough?